# PHP MySQL Insert "{$clientname}" as a string not PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, whmcs

Ok, first question so here goes,

A function that runs on activation of a module I am writing needs to put email templates into a MySQL db. The problem is these are smarty templates and use {$vars}, now when I do this in PHP the {$vars} are interpreted as PHP variables to be put into the sql query before being run.

How do I tell PHP to not interpret "{$var}" as a variable but as a string?

This is the current query:

```
$sqlEmail1 = "INSERT INTO `tblemailtemplates` (`type`, `name`, `subject`, `message`, `attachments`, `fromname`, `fromemail`, `disabled`, `custom`, `language`, `copyto`, `plaintext`)
VALUES ('general', 'IPGeek - Custom Email 1', 'Password Reset', 'Some text that contains {$company_name} among other things', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', 0)"
```

And this should be the email template the above creates:

```
Some text that contains {$company_name} among other things
```

But it creates this instead:

```
Some text that contains
```

Any help would be very gladly received!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables
> are parsed within it.
>
> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
> escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
> occur in single quoted strings.

Use `'` instead of `"`

```
echo '{$var}';
```

Or escape `$`:

```
echo "{\$var}";
```

Learn more: [php strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

**UPDATE**: Minimal effort fix is just to add `\` before `$`:

```
$sqlEmail1 = "INSERT INTO `tblemailtemplates` (`type`, `name`, `subject`, `message`, `attachments`, `fromname`, `fromemail`, `disabled`, `custom`, `language`, `copyto`, `plaintext`)
VALUES ('general', 'IPGeek - Custom Email 1', 'Password Reset', 'Some text that contains {\$company_name} among other things', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', 0)";
```

Comment: Already tried that but the issue with doing that is it breaks the query at the first ' ('general') is there another character I can use to contain the values?

Comment: You can use double quotes for the values, and single quotes for the whole string. Or you can escape the single quotes inside the string with backslash \. When I had to learn this, I imagined those strings as a sort of Baboushka puppet. One puppet contains the next puppet, every puppet you can thinnk of as a set of single or double quotes.

Comment: I have tried enclosing the entire query in `'` and escaping the `'` within the query, no luck. Enclosing the query in `"` and escaping the `$` produces the same result.
I have even tried concatenating the query `"INSERT... ".'{$var}'."..."; ` and still no luck.

Comment: Right well strangely enough now working (Thanks @des) very odd and I had escaped the `$` characters but after manually typing the query out again it seems to now work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about escaping the values properly?

- [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
- [PDO::quote()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

I'm betting there are ' (apostrophes) in your templates. If so, it would break your SQL syntax.

Comment: There are however they are properly escapaed, its the `$` that was causing the problem and had previously tried that:
`$sql = mysql_real_escape_string('It's {$your_name}');
mysql_query("INSERT... {$sql}");`
But thank you anyways :-)